# Multiple Markers at this line error, Creating Sqlite Database for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, sqlite, error-handling

When I run this code an error occurs. I am trying to create database and learn by modifying it. I copied this code from a tutorial code, it was working fine in example but I couldn't run it. Can you give more information about whay does that happen?

The error is:

Multiple markers at this line

```
- The type DatabaseHelper must implement the inherited abstract method SQLiteOpenHelper.onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, 
 int, int)
- The public type DatabaseHelper must be defined in its own file
- The type DatabaseHelper must implement the inherited abstract method SQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate(SQLiteDatabase)
```

and my code is:

```
package com.example.eos;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { //ERROR IS HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


     static final String dbName="demoDB";
     static final String employeeTable="Employees";
     static final String colID="EmployeeID";
     static final String colName="EmployeeName";
     static final String colAge="Age";
     static final String colDept="Dept";

     static final String deptTable="Dept";
     static final String colDeptID="DeptID";
     static final String colDeptName="DeptName";

     static final String viewEmps="ViewEmps";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, dbName, null,33);
    }

}
```

Comment: the information is presented quite clearly in the 3 error statements. Simply try doing what is advised there. Do you have difficulties understanding what they mean?